# php Print_f array error

Tags: php, android, arrays

I am doing a php to push GCM notification, before that I need to grab data from database and send to google GCM server.

Code is below:

```
mysql_select_db($database_gcm_gcm, $gcm_gcm);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, RegID FROM gcm_user ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());

$list_arr = array(array());

for($i=0; ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); $i++){
        $list_arr[$i]=$row;
        print_r ($row . '<br>');
     }

print_r($result . '<br>');

?>
```

It suppose to show a result like

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 1, RegID 1
    [1] => 2, RegID 2

)
```

How ever it only shows word "Array" and Resource id #4.

Which part I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$list_arr = [];

    $resultCount = mysql_num_rows($result); 
    if ($resultCount > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {   
            $list_arr[$i] = $row['id'].','.$row['RegID '];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print a query with a for. You have to use do while.

Try this code:

```
mysql_select_db($database_gcm_gcm, $gcm_gcm);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, RegID FROM gcm_user ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do{
     echo $row['id'] ." " .$row['RegID'] ."<br />";
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```